# Azure DevOps condition to execute phase only if there is a new artifact version

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm having a Release definition with multiple linked artifacts. I want to execute a certain phase/environment only if there is a new version of specific artifact is available.

I know we can achieve this through "Run this Phase" Custom Condition but I'm unable to find an expression to find and match existing artifact version on the environment.

Any ideas on where to look for will be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic variable that would hold such a value. What you can do is create a variable and update that variable on successful deployment and read that variable afterwards or query the api to find the latest successful release, etc

Comment: I'm almost successful in having this setup but stuck at assigning the artifact name to a variable. ##vso[task.setvariable variable=LastBuildNumber;isOutput=true]$LastBuildNumber does the assignment only for a single agent phase. :(

Comment: you can use yaml to share variables between phases,afair

Comment: still on TFS 2018 :( nowhere near to get updated to AzureDevOps. So there is no way other than YAML?

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I found out that for TFS 2018, using api-version=4.1-preview.6, we could do GET on Release Number,then update the required variable in a json and do PUT to update the variable value.
https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}?api-version=4.1-preview.6